# Can't rename the string that contains a command line argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm very new to C (been using C for 2 days) and I've spent the last 30 hours on tutorials-point and some random youtube videos but for the life of me I can't figure out how to put a name on the strings that I give in the command line.

So I have a file `filename.c` and the three arguments are then

```
./filename.c F22 G2
```

I know that the second argument in `argv`, that is `argv[1]` contains the string `F22` and `argv[2]` contains `G2`. I wan't to rename these two strings to `str1` and `str2`.

When I do it and try to print `str1`, I get a lot of weird characters and not `F22`. What am I messing up? See my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char* str1[] = {argv[1]};
   char* str2[] = {argv[2]};

   printf("%s\n", str1);
   return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `const char *str1 = argv[1];` and `const char *str2 = argv[2];` But first, it's good to always check `argc` to make sure that they exist.

Comment: `char* str[1]` is kinda two-dimensional array of chars, seems you need one-dimensional (string), so use `char* str = argv[i]`

Comment: @WeatherVane This worked, thanks! Why do I need the "const" infront?

Comment: If you build with verbose warnings, then the compiler should have complained about that `printf` call, where the argument type doesn't match the format specifier.

Comment: I put the `const` there because it is better not to try to overwrite the strings passed.

Comment: @WeatherVane, you can write to `argv` strings.

Comment: @anastaciu sure you can take the risk over a buffer overflow too. It's 'better' not to.

Comment: @anastaciu C allows you to do a lot of things, but not all are recommended,especially overwriting strings set up by the runtime.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes you're right, but any string in C can be overflown if you are not careful, there is nothing especially different in `argv`.

Comment: There are embedded systems where argc and argv can be defined in main(), but the content may be undefined because nothing is passed by the underlying runtime or OS.

Comment: @anastaciu the difference, though, is that you know the buffer size of your own string.

Comment: @WeatherVane, What I mean is that it can be done, not that it should be done. C11 5.1.2.2.1 - 2 "*The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination*".

Comment: @DNT, I was just pointing out that it can be done as atested by my previous comment. I appreciate you insights.

Comment: @anastaciu I see thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition

```
char* str1[] = {argv[1]};
```

defines `str1` as an array of one single `char *` element, and that single element is `argv[1]`.

The important part is that `str1` isn't a string, it's an *array* of strings.

To define a string you need to drop the braces (both square and curly):

```
char* str1 = argv[1];  // Define str1 as an alias for argv[1]
```

Of course, you could use `argv[1]` directly instead:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```

---

And for strings you should not modify, it's recommended to `const` qualify it:

```
const char* str1 = argv[1];  // Define str1 as an alias for argv[1]
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thank you! Yes I'm aware of the possibility of using argv[1] drectly in the print statement but this is just a smaller part of a bigger problem so I'm going to modify those two strings first (substringing the numer-part of the string and converting to int.) I'll mark this as accepted in 2 min.